# Problem embedding sound files in Adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe, audio

I can play a sound file in Adobe AIR if I use the the flash.media.Sound class but I have request a URL to do it. What I need to do is load it as an embedded asset in the AIR app. I have tried using mx.core.media library but this does not work either.

Here is a simple app that shows the problem:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        // Embed MP3 file.
        import flash.media.Sound;
        import mx.core.SoundAsset;
        [Embed(source="ding.mp3")]
        [Bindable]
        public var sndCls:Class;
        private var myReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("ding.mp3");
        private var snd:Sound;
        private var sndAsset:Sound;
        private var myChannel:SoundChannel;
        protected function myButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            sndAsset = new sndCls() as SoundAsset;
            myChannel = sndAsset.play();
        }

        protected function myReqButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            snd = new Sound(myReq);
            snd.play();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button id="myButton" label="Play Embedded" click="myButton_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Button id="myReqButton" label="Play Requested" click="myReqButton_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

You need ding.mp3 in the same directory to test it.

Any suggestions welcome

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Embedded resource cannot be bindable, since it is constant. Try to remove [Bindable]. If that doesn't help, post error messages (if any) or describe symptoms what's wrong.